# Filtering request and responses in RESTful MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, rest, node.js, authentication, mongoose

I have a very basic RESTful service written using the MEAN stack (MongoDb, Express.js, Angular.js, Node.js) and utilizing the Mongoose ODM.

**`Product` schema**

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true, maxlength: 250},
  _prices: [{
    amount: {type: Number,required: true,min: 0.0},
    date: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now}
  }]
});

productSchema
.virtual('price')
.get(function () {
  var price = this._prices[this._prices.length - 1];
  return price !== undefined ? price.amount : undefined;
});

productSchema.methods.setPrice = function (amount) {
  this._prices.push({amount: amount});  
};
```

The purpose of the `_prices` array and the `price` virtual property is that I want to save an audit trail of the price history.

I have a RESTful interface for `/products` supporting the usual `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`.

In my system, administrators are allowed to `POST`, `PUT`, and `DELETE`, which is obvious, however the issue arises for anonymous access.  Anonymous users are allowed to `GET` only, but the `GET` response should not include the `_prices` field, as only administrators can see the history.

**As anonymous**

```
{
  name: "Widget", 
  price: "5.99"
}
```

**As administrator**

```
{
  name: "Widget", 
  price: "5.99", 
  _prices: [
    {price: "7.25", date: "2015-02-28"}, 
    {price: "5.99", date: "2016-01-09"}
  ]
}
```

The majority of tutorials I read regarding the MEAN stack always show returning the mongoose model directly.

```
exports.getAll = function(request, response) {
  Product.find({}, '-_prices', function (err, products) {
    res.json(200, products);
  });
};
```

This is very simple to get around from the `products` controller, however, I find this to be very misplaced as this filtering logic is in the controller, and brittle in that if I add new fields to my schema, I must go back to the controller to ensure I am not exposing fields in the future.

I also have questions about going the other way, doing request validation.  It seems most tutorials have you accept user input as-is and let the mongoose validation fail.

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
  var product = new Product(request.body)

  product.save(function(error, product) {
    if (error) {
      return response.json(422, error);
    }

    response.send(201);
  });  
};
```

Having been used to ASP.NET WebApi, my views on this are slightly skewed.  I would have probably created separate view models for the request, and different view models for the response (depending on whether I'm authenticated or not), do the input validation on the request view model, and have only invariant validation within my entity.  However, I want to ensure I am doing thing the MEAN stack way.

My questions are as follows:

1. Should I rely solely on mongoose's validation for input validation, or should I write my own before it even gets to mongoose?
2. For output filtering, should I create a security / filtering  module which accepts a `Product` and returns a view-model depending on the user's context, dependent on whether they're an administrator or not?
3. Should I override the `toJSON` behavior (which is extensible in mongoose, by the way) to do the filtering?
4. Should I create a layer of abstraction between my controllers and mongoose?

My initial thought is that mongoose itself has too much responsibility, but I don't want to avoid using it if it's the best approach.

Comment: My first thought: Retrieving the price history/audit trail in the same request as retrieving the current price seems odd. Would it be simpler to have an admin-only `/producthistory` resource for this sort of thing?

Comment: This is a good point for this particular use case, however I find myself in the same scenario for other resources, for example `employee` with a field `salary`.

Comment: It sounds like a good answer for employee.salary too.  Is there a reason that to limit the number of different resources that access an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Should I rely solely on mongoose's validation for input validation, or should I write my own before it even gets to mongoose?

I think that kind of checks should be done by your service, between DB and HTTP modules, not inside DB.

> 2. For output filtering, should I create a security / filtering module which accepts a Product and returns a view-model depending on the user's context, dependent on whether they're an administrator or not?

I dislike the way something is returned from model to HTTP interface directly, but you can just use simplest method here: check the rights in request handlers and tweak the object by removing extra fields, if needed. This will take less lines.

> 3. Should I override the toJSON behavior (which is extensible in mongoose, by the way) to do the filtering?

No.

> 4. Should I create a layer of abstraction between my controllers and mongoose?

Do you mean data model layer? No. Let your controllers "control" this.